# Is it really necessary to return string instead of dictionaries in Get methods in NancyModule?

Tags: c#, json, get, .net-4.5, nancy

I'm using Nancy 1.4.3 for HTTP GET requests handling in .Net 4.5 app. I have to response with JSON object on every request. That's how my Get methods in `NancyModule` class look like:

```
Get["/getData"] = param =>
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["Success"] = true
        ["Data"] = data; //Object
    };
    return dict;
};
```

Also, there is a header adding after `Get`:

```
After += ctx => {
    ctx.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
};
```

This code works fine, but it throws a handled `RuntimeBinderException`: "Cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>` to `Nancy.Response`". Nevertheless, it answers with a correct JSON object. Have I to convert my `Dictionary` to `string` with JSON stringify method, or everything is fine?

Comment: Do you need to use a `Dictionary`? Would an anonymous type suffice?

Comment: @DavidOsborne Give an example for data above (I'm not good with C#).

Comment: Something like: `return new { Success = true, Data = data };`

Comment: @DavidOsborne Is it better for Nancy to return anonymous types in `Get`? If it's so, I can use them.

Comment: I think Nancy's flexible in what you can return (https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content-Negotiation), therefore you should return whatever's most convenient/readable/maintainable. IMHO, an anonymous type, in this situation, creates less 'noise' than the `Dictionary` solution.

Comment: @DavidOsborne But why do I get this exception? And why the code still works?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd need to take a look at the source. Regardless of the apparent correctness of the actual response, I'd want to avoid the exception in case something insidious is brewing...

Comment: I've replicated the code and I don't get the exception. It serialises the response to JSON with no issue. I used Postman to send a GET request with no headers.

Comment: @DavidOsborne I use `After` to add some headers.

Comment: How are you submitting the request? I still cannot replicate the exception.